# Find an integrable $g(x,y) \ge |e^{-xy}\sin x|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to use Fubini theorem on $$\int_0^{A} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-xy}\sin x dy dx=\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{A}e^{-xy}\sin x dx dy$$

Must verify that $\int_M |f|d(\mu \times \nu) < \infty$. I'm using the Lebesgue theorem, so far I've come up with $g(x,y)=e^{-y}$ but am not sure whether it's correct.

My argument is that if $x\in (0,1)$ then the $\sin x$ part is going to ensure that the inequality holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $g(x,y)=x\mathrm e^{-xy}$, then $|\mathrm e^{-xy}\sin x|\leqslant g(x,y)$ for every nonnegative $x$ and $y$. Furthermore, $\int\limits_0^\infty g(x,y)\mathrm dy=1$ for every $x\gt0$ hence $\int\limits_0^A\int\limits_0^\infty g(x,y)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx=A$, which is finite.

Comment: your answer is better. I ultimately turned in $g(y)= e^{-y}, y \in (1,\infty)$ and $ g(y) \equiv 1, y \in (0,1)$ was that incorrect?

Comment: This is not majorizing $f(x,y)=\mathrm e^{-xy}\sin x$ when $y$ is large and $x\lt1$ (as already mentioned in another comment).

Answer (score 2):

You can take $g(x,y)=e^{-xy}|\sin x|$ in order to get an integrable function on $[0,A]\times [0,+\infty)$. Indeed, 
$$\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-xy}dy=\frac 1x$$
and the integral $\int_0^A\frac{|\sin x|}{x}dx$ is convergent.

With $g(x,y)$, we wouldn't get a function which majorize $e^{-xy}\sin x $ everywhere (but only on for $y\geqslant 1$), which is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my $g(x,y) = e^{-y}$. Does that also work?

Comment: This works for $y\geq 1$; for $y<1$ bound it by $1$. (so yes, it almost work)

Comment: Sorry but I must disagree with the first sentence of your post. One problem is that the function $g$ suggested by the OP is not majorizing, a second problem is that the majorizing function you suggest is not the only choice, and possibly not the best.

Comment: @Did You are right, my answer was based on the first version of $g$, which was $e^{-xy}$.