# Does improper integral $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+3x+3}\,dx$ converge?

Tags: integration

Could you, please, give any reasons why this integral converges. I have tried a lot of different methods (e.g. Dirichlet's test) none of them helped me

$$\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{x\sin x}{x^2+3x+3}\,dx$$

Comment: Is contour integration (complex) allowed?

Comment: @imranfat No, it isn’t

Comment: Well, then the provided answer is also a little issue (it is not incorrect), because that assumes convergence of the integral involving $sinx/x$, so that needs to be addressed first

Comment: Wolfram gives a numerical result of it [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+xsin+x%2F(x%5E2%2B3x%2B3)+from+1+to+infinity)

Comment: What was the trouble applying Dirichlet test?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if you know that the [integral of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891812/integration-of-sinc-function), you can write
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{x^2+3x+3}{x^2+3x+3}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+3x+3}+\frac{3\sin x}{x^2+3x+3}+\frac{3\sin x}{(x^2+3x+3)x}
$$
and combine the terms to express your integral of interest via integrals that are easier to prove convergence for.

P.S. If you don't then try integration by parts (integrate $\sin x$ and derivate the rational part).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a Dirichlet test for convergence of improper integrals